# Locate element which contains visible text (ignoring formatting tags)

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to write a selenium test for a search result. The search result's snippet is formatted with `<strong>` tags:

```
<li>foo <strong>bar</strong></li>
```

How do I select all lis containing the visible text "foo bar", i.e. ignoring the `<strong>` tag(s)?
Of course I could iterate over all lis, get the text and remove the `<strong>` tags, but if it is possible with xpath alone, it would be nicer. A selenium solution would be fine, too.

Thank you

Comment: http://xpathfiddle.net/5DYWO0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.` for this purpose :

```
//li[.='foo bar']
```

`.` in this case returns all text nodes within context element, concatenated.

Answer (score -1):

```
string(//li/descendant-or-self::*)
```