# How do I assert that a page contains text with mixed formatting using Robot Framework's Selenium2Library?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

This doesn't work:

HTML Source:

```
<p>foo <strong>bar</strong></p>
```

Robot Test Case:

```
Page Should Contain    foo bar
```

How can I write a test that searches for text without having to care about text formatting tags (em, strong, span, et al.)? Do I *have to* use XPath?

Comment: Similar question, using Selenium and not Robot Framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738799/locate-element-which-contains-visible-text-ignoring-formatting-tags. I'd rather avoid having to use XPath if at all possible, because it makes the test cases more difficult to maintain for less-savvy testers.

Comment: For reference, this XPath-based locator works in my case: `Page Should Contain Element    xpath=(//*[normalize-space(.)='foo bar'])`

Comment: It's either XPath or custom library. XPath is better

Comment: You might be able to do something like this: ${text}= Get Text css=body
Should Contain ${text} foo bar